# DefaultModelBinder bool to string conversion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

It looks like the `DefaultModelBinder` is transforming a `bool` value sent to a controller that is expecting a `string` into a `string`.

true turns into "true"

I guess this is because the `DefaultModelBinder` is trying to "satisfy" the controller that is expecting a `string`?

Is there a way to control this without overriding the `DefaultModelBinder`?

Comment: Show your code!.(the `DefaultModelBinder` does not convert a `bool` to a `string` (its the other way around - every thing sent to the controller from the browser is text and will be converted to the property type)

Comment: And what do you mean _bool turns into "bool"_? A `bool` has 2 possible values - `true` or `false`

Comment: true turns into "true"

Comment: Well, if your controller expects a `string`, you'll get the exact string sent by the client: "true". Do you want a `bool` value when your actual type is `string`?

Comment: If the client sends a value of 'true' to a property which is typeof `string` then of course it will be `string`. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I'm trying to validate if the client sent true or "true"

Comment: There is no concept of true (`bool`) or "true" (`string`). Everything sent across the wire is just 'text' - a set of name/value pairs that describes the name of the property and the value of the property